# how to get the mysql table and column comments using java..?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to load the mysql table and column comments using jdbc api,but i am not able to get them....

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Connection connection = null;
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ovaledgedb?:useInformationSchema=true", username, XXXXX);
    DatabaseMetaData  dm = connection.getMetaData();
    ResultSet rs =  dm.getTables("", "schema","table", null);
    int i=0;
    while (rs.next()) {
        i++;
       System.out.println(rs.getString("TABLE_NAME"));  
         System.out.println("Comment: " + rs.getString("REMARKS"));
           }
      rs.close();
    connection.close();
}
```

please help out with some solution.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't the property `useInformationSchema` (that is without a `:`)? In any case please provide a [mcve] **including necessary DDL**, and clearly specify what is wrong.

Comment: thanks for your response @MarkRotteveel, without  **:** I am not getting any output.

Comment: Then provide a [mcve] including the relevant DDL that sets up relevant metadata objects with comments, actual output and your expected output

Answer (score -1):

connection obj is of class Connection. you need to declare it. Also you need to handle the exceptions. The url of the schema might be missing some parameters.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions @dimitris. I had done whatever you said I just keep the key logic what had tried.